# Python variable acting weird

Tags: python, algorithm

I am making a pattern recogniser and I ran into a VERY strange error. If the pattern is recognised it prints out `["x", "x", "2"]` and i set variable worked to `t`. But when I print out worked on the last line it prints out `["x", "x", "x"]`

(See the part of code marked # _____________ IMPORTANT __________ #)

```
    import random

    def check_pattern(pattern, rule):
        for i, RULE in enumerate(pattern):
            if RULE != "x":
                if rule[i] != RULE:
                    return False
        return True

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        numbers = [002,212,212,432,132,142,322,992,972,692,942,472]

        #numbers = [a.replace("\n", "") for a in numbers]

        print("Finding pattern in {}".format(numbers))

        patterns = []
        possible = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "x"]

        found = False
        pattern = ["x", "x", "x"]
        working = []
        worked = []
        for i, rule in enumerate(pattern):
            for attemptRule in possible:
                testRule = pattern
                testRule[i] = str(attemptRule)
                works = True

                for num in numbers:
                    numList = [a for a in str(num)]
                    if check_pattern(testRule, numList):
                        pass
                        #print("Pattern {} works with {}".format(t, numList))
                    else:
                        works = False
                        #print("Pattern {} doesnt work with {}".format(t, numList))
                if works:
                    # ____________________ IMPORTANT ______________________ #
                    if testRule != ['x', 'x', 'x']:
                        print(testRule)                    
                        worked = testRule
                    # ____________________ IMPORTANT ______________________ #
                    working.append(testRule)
        #print("Pattern {} works".format(working))
    print(worked)
```

Thanks.

Comment: In line 31: numList = [a for a in num] TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I now call str() on the numbers and change 1 to "1" and so on. Updating post, thanks for reply but i dont get any errors

Comment: I find it hard to read the code, what is it supposed to do? Can you give some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Uhhhh i think i already have expected input and output but ill make it more clear...

Comment: I don't really try to understand your code but `testRule = pattern` is probably the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved the problem

Comment: right now you have a SyntaxError on number `002` (line 11). To fix it, remove the 2 leading 0 then replace `str(num)` by `"%3d" % num` line 31.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answear. The problem was that i didn't clone the list and overwrote it instead. Thanks to polku i understood. Thanks everyone.